# loading services within controller class

Tags: symfony

I have been recently asked to clean up our legacy symfony code and check whether performance would be gained as well while doing it.

The first thing which I had spotted is that in almost every controller the services will be loaded via

```
 public function someAction(Request $request){

     $someService = $this->get(someService::class);
     ... there are plenty of them 

 }
```

My question: 
  Would it be better to use the dependency Injection within the Controller  constructor instead?

```
  public function __construct(SomeService1 $someService1, SomeService2 ...)
```

the service.yml file has already the autowire:true attribute enabled.
 I have previously done some research on the SO but afterwords I'm more confused and not really sure which of them is the recommendable approach.

My Symfony version is 3.3.17

Comment: Probably won't make much difference performance wise.  It won't hurt to inject but it's not going to speed things up much.  Another option is to inject your dependencies directly into the action: someAction(Request $request, SomeService $someService);  This action injection capability is still fairly new and the judges have not decided which approach is best.  But first move to 3.4 which has long term support.

Comment: @Cerad, thank you for your response. Upgrade will be definitely the next approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend the base [`AbstractController`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#controller-abstract-versus-controller) class, you can't access services directly from the container via `$this->container->get()` or `$this->get()`. Instead, you must use dependency injection to fetch services: most easily done by [type-hinting action method arguments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#controller-accessing-services):

> Don't use `$this->get()` or `$this->container->get()` to fetch services from the container. Instead, use dependency injection.

If you need a service in a controller, just type-hint an argument with its class (or interface) name. Symfony will automatically pass you the service you need:

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
// ...

/**
 * @Route("/lucky/number/{max}")
 */
public function number($max, LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $logger->info('We are logging!');
    // ...
}
```

Since 3.3, controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class:

```
# services.yml
services:
    # ...

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

By not fetching services directly from the container, you can make your services private, which has [several advantages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html#services-why-private).

There is no *runtime* performance impact for using any of these features. However, there is some performance impact in the `dev` environment. Most importantly, your container will likely be rebuilt more often when you modify your service classes.

Resources:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#fetching-services
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#fetching-and-using-services
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html